# php failed to load external entity

Tags: php, codeigniter, xhtml

Here is my codes, I am using CI, I get error  I/O warning : failed to load external entity "note.xhtml"?

index.php

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("note.xhtml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
print_r($xml);
?>
```

note.xhtml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <note>
      <to>Tove</to>
      <from>Jani</from>
      <heading>Reminder</heading>
      <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've copied your code and it works. But i see that your index.php is inside "views" folder and you have some htaccess file, so probably some rewrites are defined and it messes something with working dir. Try to use absolute path. If it does not help and you are on linux then check note.xhtml permissions.

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file(__DIR__."/note.xhtml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
print_r($xml);
?>
```

Comment: it is correct. The precise answer I have to add "/"  before my file : (."/note.xhtml").

Answer (score 0):

It seems that something is wrong with your web server configuration. 
check if your web server allows to get content from external resource or not.